# Specific Routing For Different Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can I have different routes which will be activated upon different controllers ? For example If I have controller "Age" this controller to accept this kind of routing.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/age",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", age = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

If I have another controller for example "Name" to accept this kind of routing.

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/name",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: In the first example you will pass age as an id to every action on every controller? What have you tried, and what do you want to achive?

Comment: I want every controller to run with different routing. For example when Age/Index/0 run in the Index method paramter to be "int age". When Name/Index/0 run the paramter of the Index method to be "name".

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Name",                                              // Route name
            "Name/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Name", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

A custom route for your NameController.

There are different samples at [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)